# How to handle multiple set-cookie values in react-native?

Tags: react-native, nginx, frappe

Development environment:
- nginx v1.14 on ubuntu 16
- React-Native v0.57

I'm using a frappe REST API  and the login request returns multiple cookies and I'm getting the later value, the rest are replaced. But, the data I'm looking for is sent first(sid and expires data), as I checked it on Insomnia, it got replaced by another attribute. How can I handle multiple 'Set-Cookie' values sent separately?
[image: insomnia reponse]

[image: fetch request log]

Comment: Did you find any solution? I would appreciate if you share the solution

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known bug in React Native version <0.60.

Here is the GitHub issue about it: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26280

Here is the PR that fixes it: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/27066

Try upgrading your React Native version to the latest?